# Probability of Completely New Ordering

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given some set of unique elements of length n. What is the probability that if you randomly shuffle these elements, none of them will be in their original position?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 1):

A permutation in which no element appears in its original position is called a "derangement". The topic of derangements has been thoroughly studied, and you can read about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). In particular, the probability that a permutation of $n$ elements is a derangement is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer and links to further information on this material.